# Getting the selector of $this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I basically am trying to copy my selector and create a new one.. this is what im trying to achieve...

I have many inputs in divone and dont want to list out each one in my jquery, so i would like to dynamically find the object and link to the corresponding divtwo object

```
<div id="divOne">
<input type="textbox" id="tb1" value="TEXTHERE">
<input type="textbox" id="tb2" value="TEXTHERE">
</div>
<div id="divTwo">
<input type="textbox" id="tb3" value="TEXTHERE">
<input type="textbox" id="tb4" value="TEXTHERE">
</div>

$("#divOne:input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
            var selector = ($(this).selector()); //hoping this would return input object from DivOne
            var value = ($(this).val());
            var newselector = //modify divOne object to have divTwo selector
            $(newselector).val() = value;

        });
```

Then I'd like to to save divOne text into the divTwo textbox.

I want it to look like this, only using this.  So lets say i change textbox value of tb1 to "textthere":

```
$("#divOne:input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
                    var selector = $(#divOne.attr("id", tb1"));  //this should be covered dynamically using $this or another jquery method
                    var newselector = $(#divTwo.attr("id", tb3)); //this however should be generated dynamically by selector var
                    $(newselector).val() = selector.val();

                });
```

Thanks

Comment: It's `$(this).selector`, which you should never really need, hence why it's an internal undocumented property.

Comment: when i have an alert on $(this).selector its blank @adeneo

Comment: Would help if you were more specific about what you want to happen exactly

Comment: tried to explain with updated question @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match corresponding elements you can use `index()` and `eq()`

```
var $d1Inputs = $("#divOne input").on("keyup",function(e) {
     var index = $d1Inputs.index(this);
     $('#divTwo input').eq(index).val($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: this worked, but what if i added a dropdownlist.  its an input but wouldnt i need keyup and change?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to copy the value of an input in first div to the corresponding input in second div.

So you must use `index()` to find what is the index of the input first and the use `:eq` in your selector to match only the corresponding input in second div.

```
   $("#divOne input").on("keyup",function(e) {
        $("#divTwo input:eq("+$(this).index()+")").val(($(this).val())); 
    });
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qfey8L14/3/

Comment: Would this only work if I had one textbox per div?  Because my divs have many inputs in each and also the same amount in each. Updated html in question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to do is having changes on second inputs as changes made on first div then; you could try-

```
$(document).on('keyup chage','#divOne input',function(){
   // will gives index of divone input while keyup or change event occurs
   $index=$('#divOne input').index($(this));
   // selects input from #divTwo in array from
   $divtwoinputs=$('#divTwo input');
   // now reflect the value on #divtwo inputs
   $($divtwoinputs[$index]).val($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this fix your problem if not please let me know... if fixes your problem accept this as answer...

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `input` event and the `.index()` method like so:

```
$('#divOne > :input').on('input', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#divTwo > :input').eq( index ).val( this.value );
});
```

```js
$('#divOne > :input').on('input', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#divTwo > :input').eq( index ).val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">
<input type="textbox" id="tb1" placeholder="TEXT HERE">
<input type="textbox" id="tb2" placeholder="TEXT HERE">
<select id="sl1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="divTwo">
<input type="textbox" id="tb3" placeholder="TEXT HERE">
<input type="textbox" id="tb4" placeholder="TEXT HERE">
<select id="sl2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>  
</div>
```

**Note:**
**`:input`**

> Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.